# Retag request: serverfault hard-disk -> hard-drive

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

`hard-disk` (46) seems to be a less-commonly used synonym for `hard-drive` (157).  I think it'd be worth merging the former into the latter, for cleanliness.

Answer (score 2):

ok, I merged them up.